# Create Static Page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-theme

I'm facing a big issue with the right way of implementing the static page in Wordpress. I've read almost for 5 days along now, and still can't figure out how it (should) work.

The problem i'm facing is as followed:

When I make use of the option "show latest posts" in customizer, I see the front page as it should be. I got the text of the homepage followed by the latest posts. The problem I'm facing here, is the homepage text is hard coded in my home.php. I want to be able to change that on the input field of the home in my wordpress editor.

So I understood i should make use of the index.php and create a page called "Home" and a page called "Blog". I set those pages as static page, and i'll be able to accomplish what I want. But i don't. I just can't get it done.

So I tried it with a complete new installation of WP in my local machine. Setup a brand new installation, created just 2 pages (home and blog). Go to Settings-> Reading -> Set static page: 
Homepage: Home 
Post page: Blog.
Saved changes.

Got to the homepage and i just saw my homepage. No posts up there.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a page called "Home" which is empty. It's expected and is fine. What you really need is to create a custom template (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use), and create any custom layout you want

**Extended Answer**

Create a template called homepage.tpl.php for example. Put this code inside:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Custom Homepage
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div>
  <?php    
  if ( have_posts() ) :    
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
       the_content();
     endwhile;
  endif;   
  ?>  
</div>

<div>
  <?php
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  ));
  if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
      the_title();
      /* Post loop content goes here */    
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  endif;
  ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Go the admin panel -> pages -> click edit "home". At the right sidebar select the template called "Custom Homepage". That's it.

Comment: Extended the answer. Actually home.php loops through the posts, while in custom template the default loop would be the page content -> then we'll create a custom loop to show posts

Comment: Thanx. You are so my hero!